# Keystroke events

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, keyboard, keystroke

How can I receive keystroke events on Visual Studio C++ (without Qt) for multithreading application? I tried to use SetWindowsHook, but it isn't very friendly and it requires using an additional dynamic link library. Could you advise any other way to solve it?

Comment: Is libncurses an option for you?

Comment: A [low-level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)) doesn't require the hook function to be compiled into a DLL. I'm sure we could offer alternative options, if we understood the *problem* you are trying to solve. Me, personally, I don't.

Comment: Does your application own a window? If so, you could handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` message, or use [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input). In the **Note** of the [`LowLevelKeyboardProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)#remarks): *In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, it should monitor raw input instead. This is because raw input can asynchronously monitor mouse and keyboard messages that are targeted for other threads more effectively than low level hooks can.*

Comment: I need analog  of Qt keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent*) for Visual C++

Comment: @Yusup again, a low-level keyboard hook, or a raw input hook, can give you that information, without needing you to make a DLL. Have you even looked at the links you have been given?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks a lot everyone